# Backpressure/thread safe/memory efficient in kotlin Channel?

Tags: android, kotlin, logging, thread-safety, kotlin-coroutines

I have a class `Logger` to print log in Android:

```
class Logger {
    private val scope = CoroutineScope(SupervisorJob() + Dispatchers.Default)
    private val channel = Channel<String>(50)
    private val messages = mutableListOf<String>()

    init {
        // consume message
        scope.launch {
            channel.consumeEach { message-> messages.add(message) }
        }
    }

    fun log(message: String) {
        // produce message
        scope.launch { channel.send(message) }
    }
}
```

Logs come from multiple thread, i add a `Channel` for thread safe,and Channel can also suspend the faster produce to avoid unhandled logs growing.

If the channel is full(50 message in it) and new logs are still producing, every time log() is invoked, a new coroutine is created and suspended. New coroutine objects are growing other than new message.But coroutine object is bigger than simple String.

Would it be more memory efficient if i just remove the channel and let `messages` growing.

Thread safe and backpressure strategy(suspend producer) is needed in my case. Is there any better solution?

---

Finally i found a way to do what i want:

```
class Logger {
    private val scope = CoroutineScope(SupervisorJob() + Dispatchers.Default)
    private val channel = Channel<String>(50)
    private val messages = mutableListOf<String>()
    private val logDb by lazy { Room.databaseBuilder(context, LogDatabase::class.java, "log_db").build() }

    init {
        scope.launch {
            channel.consumeEach { message-> messages.add(message) }
        }
    }

    fun log(message: String) {
        // send log to channel in non-suspend way and insert log to db when failed(buffer is full)
        channel.trySend(message).onFailure {
           val logEntity = LogEntity(UUID.randomUUID().toString(), message.toString())
           scope.launch { logDb.logDao().insert(logEntity) } 
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: If you need all messages handled regardless, why are you limiting the Channel to size 50? You are creating a problem that doesn't need to exist.

Comment: What do you try to achieve? Is adding to a list your real case or only an example? Usually, if we only need to append, then it can be done in a thread-safe manner, without synchronizing, without queues and with minimal delay. For example, you can use `ConcurrentLinkedQueue`.

Comment: If this is only an example and the real logging operation requires some time, then what is your expected behavior in the case logs are produced faster than processed? You mentioned backpressure, but your example actually don't do it. If you don't need a backpressure, then simply use unbound channel (or again: `ConcurrentLinkedQueue`) and don't `launch()` coroutines when sending a log, but add directly.

Comment: @Jorn yes, if i create `Channel(UNLIMITED)` and replace `channel.send()` with `channel.trySend()`, all the messages will be handled and no new coroutine created eveytime. But what if i want to suspend producer when buffer queue is bigger than a threshold?

Comment: @broot It is an real logging operation, the github link is https://github.com/wisdomtl/EasyLog. The expected bahavior is suspend the poducer if buffer queue is bigger than a threshold. In my code, `channel.send()` will suspend when buffer queue's size is 50.

Comment: If you actually need a backpressure and suspend the producer, then make the `log()` function suspend and don't launch new coroutines. To invoke it from outside of coroutines your best bet is probably `runBlocking()`. You can create a helper function: `logBlocking()`.